# Given a sequence, find the largest 'reverse-ordered' subsequence

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

(yes I've searched as much as I can..)
Maybe I shouldn't use sequence but there's no better way to describe it..

[revision: As stated in the answer section, subsequence is not the right description. 
A pair of numbers is the right words!]

Given a sequence of numbers and define the size of a pair of numbers from the sequence as the distance between the two numbers. Obviously the largest pair is [the first number, the last number]. The question is to find the largest pair of numbers with order opposite to the [first,last] pair.

For example, if the sequence is `{1,6,3,5,2,8}` then the answer should be 
`[6,2]` because the order of the [1,8] is increasing, and the largest pair with decreasing order is [6,2].

A side question is, can this be solved in a declarative way using SQL like statements? Specifically I am thinking of using LINQ to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: but if it were ordered shouldn't the answer be just {6,3} because 5 > 3? What would be the condition then? just that the first and last element of the sequence be ordered descending and the length of the sequence to be the largest?

Comment: Could you give more example?

Comment: Just extend the original sequence to {1,6,7,3,5,2,1,9} then it should be {6,7,3,5,2,1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the sort of problem that is suitable for SQL. It is also poorly phrased. You are really looking for pairs of numbers rather than subsequences, and the size is the distance between the two.

It can be solved **O(n)** by scanning the sequence backwards, for the smallest number after a given point, and its position. This gives `{1,2,2,2,2,8)` and `{0,4,4,4,4,5}`. Then scanning this in parallel with the original sequences gives sizes of `{0,3,2,1,0,0}`, so the largest size is for the pair `(6,2)`, which has a size of 3.

Comment: Thanks for the correction of a pair vs sequence. I've updated the original question. Your answer gave good hints. However, Why not just scan backward, for each element, look backward for those bigger than me, and the far away from me the better. Record the farthest. When done for all elements (actually no need to loop through all, just stop when your index is smaller than the largest distance found so far).

Comment: My complexity analysis skill is rusty, but I think it's O(n) give or take, since even though you need O(n) for each scan backward, but you don't need to iterate thru all of them so ...

Comment: My solution is O(n), as I said. Your suggestion appears to be O(n²).

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but I would try the following:

```
var sequence = new[] {1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 8};
var isGoingUp = sequence.First() < sequence.Last();

//if the first sequence is going up, invert the sign on the sequence
//this way we can always compare using "<"
var sequenceToCheck = sequence.Select(x => isGoingUp ? -x : x).ToList();

//initial values
int currentLength = 1; //the length of the subsequence found
int startIndex = 0; //the starting index of the subsequence

//check for each item's longest subsequence
for (int i = 0; i < sequenceToCheck.Count; i++)
{
    //go from the end towards the beginning and find the longest sequence for i
    for (int j = sequenceToCheck.Count - 1; i > j; i--)
    {
        if (sequenceToCheck[i] < sequenceToCheck[j])
        {
            //found i's longest subsequence
            if (currentLength < j - i + 1)
            {
                startIndex = i;
                currentLength = j - i + 1;
            }
            break; //don't check any smaller sequences for i
        }
    }

    if(sequenceToCheck.Count - i < currentLength)
        break; //no need to check any more, no sequence past this can be longer
}

var subsequence = sequence.Skip(startIndex).Take(currentLength);
```

You should be able to implement this solution in LINQ as well, by computing the distances from each point to the matching number (from the end).

---

Implementing this in SQL however would be slightly more difficult, although you can definitely do it. Here's my attempt and a [working SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1c85/10):

```
WITH firstValue AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 value
    FROM t
    ORDER BY id
), lastValue AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 value
    FROM t
    ORDER BY id DESC
), seqToCheck AS (
    SELECT id, 
        CASE WHEN lastValue.value > firstValue.value THEN 0-t.value 
             ELSE t.value 
        END AS value
    FROM t
    CROSS JOIN firstValue
    CROSS JOIN lastValue
), subSequences AS (
    SELECT s1.id, COALESCE(MAX(s2.id - s1.id + 1),1) AS distance
    FROM seqToCheck AS s1
    LEFT JOIN seqToCheck AS s2 ON s1.value < s2.value AND s2.id > s1.id
    GROUP BY s1.id
), longestSubSequence AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 id, distance
    FROM subSequences
    ORDER BY distance DESC
)
SELECT t.value
FROM t
INNER JOIN longestSubSequence AS l ON t.id >= l.id AND t.id < l.id + l.distance
ORDER BY t.id
```

This assumes you have an ascending identity column `id` which *does not contain gaps*. You can also do `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY xxxxx)` if you do not have such a thing.

You could probably make it a little more complicated in order to make use of indexes.

Comment: Thanks! i realized asking for SQL like is really too much for this.

Answer (score 0):

One good algorithm is to make comparisons from outside inwards and break once you get what you need.Since your target sequence needs comparison between the first and the last,the problem is rather easy to implement. Shrinking the sequence from outside assures you that you get your largest required sequence faster.

In your case,
**{1,6,3,5,2,8}**

```
1. Compare 1 and 8 
2. Compare 1 and 2
3. Compare 6 and 8
4. Compare 6 and 2 and you got your sequence
```

Comment: But it will be still O(n^2) in the worst case (the same as if I go from inside).